# i have a problem with logging to my wordpress site using cURL

Tags: php, authentication

my code is:

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";

    $postFields = array(
        "user_login" => "email",
        "user_pass" => "pass",

    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/wp-admin/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
exit();
    if ($response->status) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($response);

        foreach($html->find('a[href^=post.php?id=]') as $link)
            echo $link->plaintext . "<br>";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

i want to login to my WordPress website using cURL, When i use this code nothing happens, it just only showed me the login page but the inputs are not filled. 
what should i do? am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) that comes bundled with Wordpress?

Comment: My first goal is login in WordPress, This is just a test than i want to login to other platforms with the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your script, first the keys of postField, wordpress has "log", "pwd" in the name, not "user_login" & "user_pass" thoose is the ids.

So, your array would to be:

```
$postFields = array(
        "log" => "email",
        "pwd" => "pass",
);
```

And then, the endpoint is incorrect, you need to query the "wp-login.php".

So, your endpoint would to be:

```
https://example.com/wp-login.php
```